# Docker NFS volume using Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, nfs, docker-volume

Given a simple example such as

```
$ docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
    --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
    foo
```

How can I do the same using Ansible? I tried for example

```
- name: NFS volume mount
  docker_volume:
    driver: "local"
    driver_options:
      type: nfs
      o: "addr=192.168.1.1,rw"
      device: /path/to/dir
    volume_name: foo
```

Which will create the volume without errors but it will fail when the volume is used with `docker_container` module.

```
TASK [oracle-database : docker_container] **************************************
fatal: [oracle]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error starting container 1beb3254e25a8fe47cd78e803a2050f24020cf72e138472d7d14d963e02bec7f: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"{\"message\":\"error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /path/to/dir:/var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data, data: addr=192.168.1.1: invalid argument\"}\")"}
```

When I create the volume using Ansibe

```
[root@oracle ~]# docker volume inspect oracle-dumps
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-31T02:07:14-07:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data",
        "Name": "foo",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/path/to/dir",
            "o": "192.168.1.1,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

When I create the volume manually using `docker volume create`:

```
[root@oracle ~]# docker volume inspect oracle-dumps
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-31T02:07:14-07:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data",
        "Name": "foo",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/path/to/dir",
            "o": "192.168.1.1,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

The labels attribute aside, looks pretty much the same.

`docker inspect` of the container is the same with regards to the volume

```
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "oracle-dumps",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data",
            "Destination": "/otherpath/to/dir",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
```

So the conclusion is that there is a bug but where? Ansible? docker-py? Docker?

The workaround is

```
- name: Create dump volume
  command:
    cmd: "docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw --opt device=:/path/to/dir foo"
```

Comment: did you tried to remove the "" around the parameter of o ?

Comment: Yes, tried that, same problem

Comment: Mhm, are you sure you removed the volumes between your different tests? If I run the same `docker volume create` as yours, I do get `"o": "addr=192.168.1.1,rw"` and not `"o": "192.168.1.1,rw"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the missing `:`. The device path should be `:/path/to/dir`

```
- name: NFS volume mount
  docker_volume:
    driver: "local"
    driver_options:
      type: nfs
      o: "addr=192.168.1.1,rw"
      device: :/path/to/dir
    volume_name: foo
```